# WinRAR The file is corrupt

Tags: laptop

How can I fix this
I downloaded a game and want to extract it using WinRAR. This error shows me Grounded.v0.2.0 \ Grounded \ Maine \ Content \ Paks \ Maine-WindowsNoEditor.pak. The file is corrupt

Comment: https://windowsreport.com/fix-corrupt-archive/

Comment: Why were you downloading this game in the form of a RAR? This game is currently in early access or public beta and is published in forms not including RAR files, making me wonder if you're dealing with a cracked version.

Comment: Yes, I deal with crack because I am trying to create mods to play so I need to change some game files and because Steam does not allow the game to play if I change some files so I want a crack version for that

Comment: Isn't piracy/cracking off-topic here?

Comment: Michael Harvey     ////I am not trying to talk about piracy / cracking because I am talking about a problem with WinRAR and I solved it not with your help. So if you are not helping, keep your answers to yourself.